# Bubble sort takes a long time then segfaults

Tags: c, bubble-sort

> Given an integer `n`, write a C program to count the number of digits that are in the same position after forming an integer `m` with the digits in `n` but in ascending order of digits. For example, if the value of `n` is 351462987 then value of `m` will be 123456789 and digits 4 and 8 will be in the same position.

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void bubble(int a[],int length)
{
    for (int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<length;j++)
        {
            if (a[j]>a[j+1])
            {
                int t=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=t;
            }
        }
    }
}
int check(int a[],int b[],int length)
{
    int count=0;
    for (int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if (a[i]==b[i])
        {
            count=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
int length(int n)
{
    int l;
    while (n!=0)
    {
        n=n/10;
        l++;
    }
    return l;
}
void main()
{
    int n,arrn[100],temp[100];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int l=length(n);
    for (int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        arrn[l-i-1]=n%10;
        temp[l-i-1]=arrn[l-i-1];
        n=n/10;
    }
    bubble(temp,l);
    int c=check(arrn,temp,l);
    printf("%d",c);
}
```

I am able to compile the code but when I execute it it takes a long time only to show segmentation fault.

Comment: Check your bubble sort against the algorithm here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/

Comment: Bubble sort is an overkill for sorting digits. Take a look at *counting sort*.

Comment: How 0 in a number should be handled? Should we assume no 0?

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer, **use a debugger**.

Here are some problem with your code:

- In `length` function, `l` is not initialized and as such can have an arbitrary initial value. In your case, you probably want to start at 0.

  ```
  int l = 0;
  ```
- Your `check` function probably don't do what you want. As written `count` is not a count but the index of a position where numbers match. As there is a `break` statement in the block, the loop will exit after the first match so the return value would be the position of the first match or 0 if no match was found.
- Your `bubble` function goes one item too far when `i` is equal to `length - 1` as you access item `a[j + 1]` in the inner loop which is out of bound. In that case, it is simpler to start at 1 instead of 0 and compare item at index `i - 1` with item at index `i`.

Some extra notes:

- It is recommended to add whitespace around operators and after a comma separating multiple declarations to improve readability. Here are some example of lines with improved readability.

  ```
  int n, arrn[100], temp[100];
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)…
  if (a[i] == b[i])…
  arrn[l - i - 1] =n % 10;
  temp[l - i - 1] = arrn[l - i - 1];
  int check(int a[], int b[], int length)
  ```
- Instead of writing multiple functions at once, you should write one function and ensure it works properly. By the way, the loop that split a number into digits could also be a function.

  - Try the function with small number (ex. 12 or 21)
  - Use better name for your variable. `arrn` and `temp` are not very clear. `original` and `sorted` might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Your length function has a very obvious bug in it. What value does `l` start with? You don't initialise it so it could start with any value and cause undefined behaviour. You should set it to 0.

```
int length(int n)
{
    int l = 0;
    while (n!=0)
    {
        n=n/10;
        l++;
    }
    return l;
}
```

Comment: Not in the code you've posted in the question. If you make that change, does it work?

Comment: No it didn't. I checked the individual functions with my own values and they seem just fine. Turns out something wrong happens when I combine all of them for this program. But I will let you know if I find anything.

Comment: @AbhijithKumar Then you need to learn how to correctly test your code… While you might get undefined result with `length` and `bubble` that might sometime even be good, the function `check` will systematically give wrong result for most inputs that have some matches.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't be sorting or reading it into an int - to enable handling leading zeros in the digit string.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXNUMLEN 200
int main(void)
{
   int i, j, l, x=0;
   char numin[MAXNUMLEN], numout[MAXNUMLEN];
   int digits[10]={0};

   printf("enter a string of digits: " );
   fgets(numin, sizeof(numin), stdin); 
   printf("\nsaw   : %s", numin );

   // walk string once, counting num of each digit present
   l=strlen(numin);
   for(i=0; i<l; i++) {
      if( isdigit(numin[i]) ) {
         int d = numin[i] - '0'; // char digit to int digit
         digits[d]++;
      }
   }

   // for each digit present, write the number of instances of the digit to numout
   for( i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
      for(j=0; j<digits[i]; j++)
         numout[x++] = '0'+i; // int digit back to char digit
   }
   numout[x]='\0'; // terminate string
   printf("sorted: %s\n", numout );
}
```

Sample run:

```
watson:digsort john$ ./ds
enter a string of digits: 002342123492738234610

saw   : 002342123492738234610
sorted: 000112222233334446789
watson:digsort john$
```

Comment: The program should count digits at the same position. So if you already count digits, then `numout` is not necessary as we could directly count those using nested loops with `digits` and `numin` variables and a variable for the result.

Comment: @Phil1970 I never thought about that. Thanks a lot for pointing it out.